# Autosupply user input to Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch

I'm writing a Windows batch file. On the ordinary command line, we'd have:

```
mysql -u root -p dbname
Enter password: [types password]
show tables;
```

Is there a way I can supply the password, and 'show tables' in the batch file so the user doesn't have to type it in - they can just run the batch file?

Answer (score 2):

Password:

```
mysql -u root --password=p4ssw3rd dbname
```

Commands:

```
mysql ... -e "show tables;"
```

```
echo show tables; | mysql ...
```

```
(
    echo foo;
    echo bar;
) | mysql ...
```

```
mysql ... < commands.txt
```

Comment: very good! i normally use "<"